# Multiple Tools Tip Effect

Tags: jquery

I need to make the tool tip more than one tools tip in jQuery, but I'm very new with this can some one help me out of the problem please.

```
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#menu_eric").tooltip({ effect: 'fade'});
  });
 </script>


 <!-- Link 1 Image 1 -->
  <a id="menu_eric">Link 1 </a>
 <img class="tooltip" src="mouse_hover_pic1.jpg">




 <!-- Link 2 Image 2 -->
    <a id="menu_eric">Link 2 </a>
    <img class="tooltip" src="mouse_hover_pic2.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Are both images in the same div-container?

If they are you could leave out the id attribute of the images and use this:

```
$('#IdOfYourDivContainer img').tooltip({ effect : 'fade'});
```

It's always better not to use so many IDs and classes

Comment: "It's always better not to use so many IDs and classes" - I don't agree with this statement at all, especially for sites using heavy CSS or jQuery.  Perhaps it's a preference, but there are many cases where not having a class or ID to grab onto makes things worse, not better.

Comment: I personally prefer to reduce the amount of classes and IDs, partly because I'm always running out of names =D. However, in my opinion it's better to create a ID and address the following nodes like `#id tagName`. I also agree with your opinion, if you are using heavy CSS or jQuery you'll have a large number of classes at the end. But my goal is always, to reduce the number of them.

Comment: Maybe we'll just add "within reason" to it and call it good?  Like with anything, it's possible to go overboard.  After some time to think, it's really only the CSS that makes it necessary - and usually just to account for IE8 and lower to avoid filter declarations and such.  Child selectors are a beautiful thing.  Balancing simplicity with functionality should be what we strive for - I'll try to remember that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't have two items with the same id - that's your biggest issue there.  Change `id=` to `class=`, then change `$("#menu_eric")` to `$(".menu_eric")`.

Alternately, give your two `<a>` tags different id's - menu_eric1 and menu_eric2, for example.  Then either call `$("#menu_eric1").tooltip({ effect: 'fade'});
$("#menu_eric2").tooltip({ effect: 'fade'});` or `$("#menu_eric1, #menu_eric2").tooltip({ effect: 'fade'});`

If these don't fix your issue, it would help to know which of the 30+ jQuery tooltip plugins you're using.

Comment: Hello @SickHippie I use this one http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/index.html
will let you know in few minutes it work or not.

Comment: How the jQuery know witch link be long to witch link, can you ex-plane for me please.

Comment: Without getting too technical, it basically attaches a listener to the elements you specify in the JS.  When the mouse hovers over an element that it's listening to, it will display the tooltip you specify - in this case, where you have `class="tooltip"` specified.  Don't forget to accept the answer if your problem is fixed!